# Callback in C++ class for topic subscription

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am trying to make a class for the joints in my robotic arm. And this class is as below:

```
class joint_move{
    ros::Publisher joint_pub;
    ros::Subscriber joint_status;   
    void move_joint_topic(double);
    dynamixel_msgs::JointState joint_state;
    void joint_state_cb(const dynamixel_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg) { joint_state = *msg; }
public:
    joint_move(ros::NodeHandle, int);
};
```

And the definition for constructor is as below:

```
joint_move::joint_move(ros::NodeHandle nh, int id)
{
    joint_pub = nh.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("joint1_controller/command", 1000);
    joint_status = nh.subscribe("joint1_controller/state", 10, this->joint_state_cb);
}
```

But during the call of the nh.subscribe, there is a compilation error, that a non-static member function can't be called like this.
I did some search myself, and came to know it is difficult to have a callback in c++.

So has somebody have made some class like this.
Or is there any better implementation possible to achieve this kind of modularity.
Or can somebody please let me know how to implement this.

Regards,
Saurabh

---

Edit: I also tried to make this function as static in the class itself. But then I am not able to access the member variable i.e joint_state in the callback function.
So that is useless for me.

I tried to make a wrapper also, to which I can pass this pointer. But if we make any function as static in a class, then we can't use this pointer also.

Upto now I didn't find any solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/291492/callback-in-c++-class-for-topic-subscription/) by [saurabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28038/saurabh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2018-05-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers - Subscribing to a Topic - Callback Types - Class Methods](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Class_Methods): for callbacks that are methods (ie: class members) you need to provide a pointer to the object that the method should be invoked on.

For your ctor initialisation of the `Subscriber`, that would be `this`.

Also: you don't register methods as callbacks with `this->..`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [saurabh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28038/saurabh/) on 2018-05-19**:
Thanks gvdhoorm, it is working.